# How can I access all sub-folders in the current working directory using perl?

Tags: perl

I am trying to access all sub-folders in the current working directory. And then I want to run a program in each sub-folder. How can I do this? My  code gave the following error:

Too many arguments for glob at ./analysis.pl line 13, near ""08")"
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at ./analysis.pl line 13.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use File::chdir;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;

# current working directory
my $dir = cwd();

# subfolders pathway
my @dirs = glob ($dir/*);

# input file for program
my $data="ethanol.txt";

# enter to each subfolder
foreach $dir ( @dirs ) {
    chdir($dir) or die "Cannot cd to $dir: $!\n";

    # Run for ethanol
    system("echo 1 1 | program -o $data");  

    chdir("..");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you actually meant to say was, `glob("$dir/*")`, but *I like* using [`File::Find::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) for this type of task:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict;
use warnings; 

use Cwd;
use File::Find::Rule;

my $dir     = cwd();
my @subdirs = File::Find::Rule->directory
                              ->in( $dir );

foreach my $subdir ( @subdirs ) {
   # do stuff
}
```

Comment: it works. Thanks. You are wonderful. But I am just wondering how can I run my old code?

Comment: I believe you just need to place `$dir/*` in a string.. like: `"$dir/*"`

Comment: Hunter's code works. My old code doesn't work. I am also trying to run it.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you have loaded [`File::chdir`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::chdir) but fon't use it in your program. It can be a very useful module, and is particularly applicable in this situation. It works by defining a magic variable `$CWD` that evaluates to the current directory when read, and alters the current directory when written to. That means it can replace `Cwd` and `chdir`.

In addition, you can use `local` to localise changes to the working directory so that the original location is restored at the end of a block.

Take a look at this rewrite of your own code that should do what you need.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::chdir;

my $data = 'ethanol.txt';

while (my $node = glob '*' ) {

    next unless -d $node;

    local $CWD = $node;
    system "echo 1 1 | program -o $data";
}
```

Comment: @perlselami: The choice is absolutely up to you, but I wonder why you decided against this solution after initially accepting it? Understanding this will help me to write better answers in the future. Thank you.

Comment: Your code also works. But when I try to create a directory for the result/output file of program in while loop your code doesn't accept it.

Comment: @perlselami: Ah okay. I don't see why that wouldn't work. You can just do `mkdir 'subdir'` to create a directory within the current working directory. Note that `local $CWD = $node` changes the current directory.