# How can I get sub-folder names in the working directory using perl?

Tags: perl

I have a few sub-folders in the main folder. My program will do some calculations in each sub-folder. Firstly the code will create the "result" folder in main folder for all calculations. And, for the calculation in each sub-folder I want to create a folder in the "result" folder. But they should have the same name as sub-folder.

My working directory is "/home/abc/Desktop/test". The "test" is my main folder. There are "a", "b" and "c" sub-folders in "test" folder. My code creates the "result" folder in "test" main folder. But it also should create "a", "b" and "c" sub-folders in "result" folder. How can I fix my code?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings; 
use File::Path qw/make_path/;
use Cwd;

my $dir     = cwd();

opendir (DIR, $dir) or die "Unable to open current directory! $!\n";
my @subdirs = readdir (DIR) or die "Unable to read directory! $!\n";
closedir DIR;

my $result_path = "$dir/results";
make_path("$result_path");

foreach my $subdir ( sort @subdirs ) {

chdir($subdir) or die "Cannot cd to $dir: $!\n";

make_path("$result_path/$subdir");

 system("echo '1 0' | program -f data.mol -o $result_path/$subdir outfile.txt");

chdir("..");

}
```

Comment: With the changed code, I cannot reproduce the problem. `$folder` holds the directory name.

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo. I edited my code. But it doesn't give what I want.

Comment: Well, the code as given doesn't do anything. How do you check the result? The error is probably there, not here.

Comment: I printed to screen it.

Comment: Add it to the code in the question.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. What's the problem you're having.

Comment: I suspect you are printing `$dir` instead of `$folder`?

Comment: Maybe a simple `next if $subdir == 'test'`?

Comment: `next if $subdir == 'test'` didn't fix it. Because "test" is not a sub-folder. It is main folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think [`File::Find::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Find::Rule) is a good choice for this problem. The module's speciality is recursively searching directory trees, and here you just want a list of all the directories in a single folder. That can very simply be done with `grep -d, glob '*'`

Here's a version that uses the [`File::chdir`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::chdir) module as per your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28907858). It avoids the need for `Cwd` and `File::Basename`, and it allows you to localise the current working directory so that there is no need for `chdir '..'` at the end of each loop.

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

use File::chdir;

my @folders = grep -d, glob '*';

my $result_path = "$CWD/result";
mkdir $result_path;

for my $folder ( @folders ) {
  my $result_folder = "$result_path/$folder";
  mkdir $result_folder;
  local $CWD = $folder;
  system("echo '1 0' | program -f data.mol -o $result_folder/output.txt");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But your code created "a", "b", "c" and "result" folders in the "result" folder.

Comment: @perlselami: Okay fixed. It now gets the list of subdirectories *before* creating `result`.

Answer (score 1):

```
File::Find::Rule->directory->in( $dir );
```

finds all directories recursively down the directory tree with starting point `$dir`. For each directory it finds, you are taking the basename.

So, when it comes across `$dir/test/a`, the `basename` of that is `a`, and your code goes ahead and creates `result/a`.

I suspect you do not need to find *all* the directories in a tree -- but given your jumbled problem description it is not easy to be certain.

Maybe you just want to `opendir` the directory, `readdir` all the entries keeping only directories other than `.` and `..`, and `closedir` when you are done instead of traversing the entire tree under `$dir`.

Comment: I would rather you updated your question with a clear and concise description of your problem. I wish @Borodin hadn't given you the fish, because now you have no incentive to fix your question.

Comment: Thanks @Sinan, I updated  my question and code. How can I fix it?